# Get Class object from another Class JNI

Tags: android, c++, c, class, java-native-interface

***Java code:***

```
public class ParentClass
{
    class ChildClass
    {
        public String strUrl;         

        /**
         * Standard Constructor.
         */
        public ChildClass( )
        {
            strUrl = "";
        {
    }

    // Some code goes here ....
}
```

How you can see I have `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` in it. Now from my JNI code I want to get `ChildClass` and call it's constructor. In JNI I have `ParentClass` object.

What must I do to get `ChildClass` object from `ParentClass` and call `ChildClass` functions or set members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oracle java the syntax will be

```
env->FindClass("ParentClass$ChildClass");
```

This may works also for android.
Plus constructor of inner class have additional parameter, reference to outer class.